# How are animations done in blender?

Tags: animation

When I try to make an animation, evrything goes in one motion. For example lets say I have two objects. If I want to make one object to move, then make it stationary, and then the other to move, then make that one stationary, then on the first object the same process. I can't do that. If I try and do that, both of the objects will move together. How to do it?

Comment: Did you use seperate Objects?

Comment: Did you accidentally parent the objects together? If you did, there will be a black dashed line between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just need to add another keyframe for the second object that should stay on its current position until the first moving object has finished its movement. Otherwise the position of your second object would also be interpolated between the keyframes.

In this example the location of both objects is keyframed at frame 1 the sphere reaches its final location at frame 20. The cube stops at frame 42. To have the cube stand still another keyframe for the cubes starting position is added at frame 20.

[image]

Comment: I think I had another similar issue (I forgot about it), but this works for now, thanks.